# How can I execute a dotnetcore project that runs inside a docker container from the command prompt?

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I created a **dotnetcore WebAPI** with **Visual Studio 2019 16.0 Preview** which has docker support. I'm using the windows container and is able to execute the application from Visual Studio IDE. I can also debug the app.

The way I used to run **dotnetcore WebAPI** app was execute the `dotnetcore run` from the project folder in the command prompt. The project will be rebuilt if I make a change in the code. I attach the Vi**sual Studio t**o the **dotnetcore** process to debug.

1. How can I do the same for the application that runs inside a Docker
   Container?
2. What command that I need to run from the project folder?

Comment: Needs more focus. This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only. [ask]

Comment: Behind the scene Visual Studio calls several `docker` commands, which are the things you need to learn yourself (like build images from Dockerfile, and launch containers). A Docker book should have all necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read on docker. You can find some very good documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/

You need to build an image first. Go to your application folder where your Dockerfile is stored open powershell and type

```
docker build .
```

your image will be build and then confirm that you have a new image by

```
docker images
```

with the command above you can see all the available images that you have locally.

After finding the right image you run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 <image name or id>
```

-p is port mapping, it is needed because because docker has its own network.

The above are the absolute basic commands. Take a look at the documentation url it will help you a lot.